# Crashed when accessing property defined in BFPaperButton subclass

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift, init, uicontrol

I am working on creating a customized button in Swift.

When I subclassed UIButton class, it works fine.

But it crashed when I replace super class with BFPaperButton (https://github.com/bfeher/BFPaperButton)

I have fixed the init method name conversion error with:

```
#define initFlat initWithFlat
#define initFlatWithFrame initWithFlatWithFrame
#define initRaised initWithRaised
#define initRaisedWithFrame initWithRaisedWithFrame
```

Then I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing the new defined property:

```
(An UserCountButton Instance).countLabel.text = ...
```

This is my implementation:

```
import UIKit

class UserButton: BFPaperButton {
    let footerLabel = UILabel()
    override init() {
        super.init(flatWithFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 3, height: 100))
        addSubview(footerLabel)
        layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        footerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: bounds.width, height: 40)
        footerLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        footerLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        footerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
    }
    override init(raisedWithFrame frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(raisedWithFrame: frame)
    }
    override init(flat: ()) {
        super.init(flat: ())
    }
    override init(flatWithFrame frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(flatWithFrame: frame)
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}

class UserCountButton: UserButton {
    let countLabel = UILabel()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        addSubview(countLabel)
        countLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 90)
        countLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        countLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        countLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(32)
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
}
```

Is that a bug or some what? How can I fix it? (I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 5)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the problem is that you are trying to change stuff on your `countLabel`, but you have defined it via `let` which makes it immutable. Try changing that to `var`, and then setting all of it's properties.

Also, it should be noted that I believe you need to do all the subview initialization BEFORE you call `addSubview`, for both your `UserCountButton` and your `UserButton`.

Comment: I've tried doing that. But unfortunately, it's not the problem. 'var' means that the pointer is mutable. The property can also be changed if it was defined by 'let'. And subview addition at that place is just OK. Without convenience init, the process of initialization is: up process(all before super.init), down process(all after super.init). I can't agree with your answer.

Comment: Ah, well in that case, not sure what your problem is.